# Problema propiedad setVisible de jlabel en java no funciona

Tags: java, netbeans

hola tengo el siguiente codigo el cual segun una condicion oculto o muestro el label al menos eso intento. por defecto deje el label oculto, pasa por la condicion pero no muestra el label les dejo el codigo  aca abajo. gracias de antemano.

```
private void txtrutFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                 


    try{
        System.out.println("el resultado es "+ existe(txtrut.getText()));
        if(existe(txtrut.getText())==1){
            msg_rut.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("pase por el if");
        }
        else{ msg_rut.setVisible(false);}    
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("problema al validar el rut en bd"+ e.getMessage());
    }




}
```

Comment: msg_rut esta siendo agregado al jframe?

Comment: por defecto agregalo como visible(solo para probar)

Comment: si esta agregado. necesito que este oculto al principio

Comment: ok intentare probar eso

Comment: funciona asi dejandolo visible al principio . pero necesito que este oculto al principio

Comment: entonces jamas entra a if(existe(txtrut.getText())==1){

Comment: si entra por que imprimi un mensaje para ver si pasaba por el if e imprime dicho mensaje

Comment: entonces luego entra a  `else{ msg_rut.setVisible(false);}`

Comment: Has probado de llamar a `invalidate()` (del elemento padre) después de cambiar la visibilidad de msg_rut?

Comment: no se como hacer eso. soy nuevo en el lenguaje java

Comment: hice de poner el invalidate al elemento padre pero no funciono

Comment: y que hace existe() ?